# SceneKit: SCNRenderingAPI

Tags: swift, scenekit, metal

I am trying to use the PhysicallyBased lighting model for my SCNView... but in order to do that, I must set the view's renderingAPI property to SCNRenderingAPIMetal.

The game technology I chose was SceneKit, not Metal, so that may be the problem. However, I think that is just a template. Shouldn't I be able to import the Metal framework somehow?

edit: I get the error saying that the view.renderingAPI property is immutable...

Comment: Only metal support physical based lighting currently.

Comment: I thought Metal would be supported by any of the newer devices. I'm using an iPhone X.

Comment: Not for simulator however

Comment: OpenGL es still being used now.

Comment: What do you mean? I’m running the app on an iPhone X, not the simulator.

Comment: Rendering api has three mode: automatic metal and OpenGL es. It has nothing to do with game technology. If you choose SceneKit and running on an iPhone, you can use physicallybases lighting if you choose auto for scnview.

Comment: Thanks, man. I used the print(view.renderingAPI) to try to see the value for my rendering API but all it said was RenderingAPI in the console. How do I choose auto? Or metal?

Comment: Should be metal

Comment: I think you’re right... the camera effects I was trying to implement seem to be working... wantsHDR, depthOfField, etc. ... and I think those require the physically based lighting model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SceneKit is an abstraction built upon OpenGL/Metal. It wraps commonly used operations, shading models, etc... in a nice framework so programmers don't have to implement an entire rendering pipeline. You should not need to drop down to Metal to do commonly supported operations such as physically based rendering.

To implement PBR, you need to specify that your object is using PBR and set the various inputs necessary to render the effect:

```
let material = firstNode.geometry?.firstMaterial
material?.lightingModelName = SCNLightingModelPhysicallyBased
material?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "albedo.png")
material?.roughness.contents = UIImage(named: "roughness.png")
material?.metalness.contents = UIImage(named: "metalness.png")
material?.normal.contents = UIImage(named: "normal.png")
```

You should only need to drop down to Metal if you are trying to implement an effect that is not supported by SceneKit. Hope that helps!

Comment: That definitely helps. Definitely. Thanks so much.